# Apache benchmark inconsistent

Tags: php, apache, benchmarking

I am testing my website homepage on a local server using apache benchmark and I would have expected some consistent results, given that there are no eternal influences on the site as it is local.

However, I am getting wildly different results, can anyone explain this:

```
ab -n 10 -c 1 -g benchmark-data.txt http://dev.local/
```

-

```
starttime       seconds ctime   dtime   ttime   wait
Mon Nov 26 13:53:49 2012        1353938029      0       693     693     670
Mon Nov 26 13:53:52 2012        1353938032      0       891     891     865
Mon Nov 26 13:53:48 2012        1353938028      0       975     975     950
Mon Nov 26 13:53:51 2012        1353938031      0       1212    1212    1191
Mon Nov 26 13:53:53 2012        1353938033      0       1344    1344    1324
Mon Nov 26 13:53:45 2012        1353938025      0       1352    1353    1335
Mon Nov 26 13:53:54 2012        1353938034      0       1398    1398    1379
Mon Nov 26 13:53:49 2012        1353938029      0       1409    1409    1391
Mon Nov 26 13:53:55 2012        1353938035      0       1430    1430    1411
Mon Nov 26 13:53:46 2012        1353938026      0       1509    1509    1489



starttime       seconds ctime   dtime   ttime   wait
Mon Nov 26 14:01:51 2012        1353938511      0       515     515     497
Mon Nov 26 14:01:49 2012        1353938509      0       685     685     667
Mon Nov 26 14:01:49 2012        1353938509      0       752     752     731
Mon Nov 26 14:01:51 2012        1353938511      0       870     870     848
Mon Nov 26 14:01:50 2012        1353938510      0       872     872     855
Mon Nov 26 14:01:48 2012        1353938508      0       894     894     873
Mon Nov 26 14:01:47 2012        1353938507      0       902     902     883
Mon Nov 26 14:01:45 2012        1353938505      0       933     933     909
Mon Nov 26 14:01:46 2012        1353938506      0       1202    1202    1184
Mon Nov 26 14:01:42 2012        1353938502      0       3009    3009    2991


starttime       seconds ctime   dtime   ttime   wait
Mon Nov 26 14:02:45 2012        1353938565      0       916     917     892
Mon Nov 26 14:02:40 2012        1353938560      0       994     994     974
Mon Nov 26 14:02:44 2012        1353938564      0       1032    1032    1009
Mon Nov 26 14:02:39 2012        1353938559      0       1255    1255    1235
Mon Nov 26 14:02:37 2012        1353938557      0       1319    1319    1302
Mon Nov 26 14:02:36 2012        1353938556      0       1355    1355    1338
Mon Nov 26 14:02:41 2012        1353938561      0       1375    1376    1350
Mon Nov 26 14:02:48 2012        1353938568      0       1429    1429    1405
Mon Nov 26 14:02:46 2012        1353938566      0       1689    1689    1663
Mon Nov 26 14:02:42 2012        1353938562      0       1982    1982    1964
```

Comment: I'd try with a number higher than `-n 10` to get some more meaningful averages, try 1000+. There are so many possibilities for why the server may have a slow start...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the chance of external interference is low, because you are running the site in localhost, it is still possible to get varying results because of other factors like

- The current load on your machine
- Memory usage by other apps

etc.

Also try to run the benchmark with higher values of `n`. Something like `-n100` or may be even `-n1000`